# __weak SLComposeViewController cause crash in IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, facebook, weak-references, slcomposeviewcontroller, retain-cycle

I have a problem with SLComposeViewController in IOS 8. I want to show Facebook sharing window and after it's done - show Twitter sharing window. That's why I need to use completion blocks and to avoid retain cycles I have to use *__weak SLComposeViewController*, but when I call

> [viewController presentViewController:facebookSLController animated:YES completion:Nil];

my `facebookSLController` is nil. It's because of `__weak`. But why it didn't crash in IOS 7?
And how can I solve this problem? Here is part of code:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    __weak SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:text];

    //When facebook sharing end - we start twitter sharing
    [controller setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self shareTwitterImage:image withText:strGetApp fromViewController:viewController];
    }];


    [controller addImage:image];

    [viewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are messing with memory management without knowing what you're doing. Your code makes no sense. Declaring a variable `weak` and assigning a newly created instance to that variable means that that instance will go out of existence immediately - because there is nothing to retain it. Normally, the strong reference of the variable is what would retain it, but by declaring the variable `weak` you have prevented that. Thus you may expect `controller` to vanish in a puff smoke the instant you declare it - and that is what it's doing. This code *never* worked correctly, in iOS 7 or in iOS 8.

If you want to pass the view controller referred to thru `controller` thru a weak reference into the block, then do that; take *another* reference, a weak reference, to `controller` and let it pass into the block (and do the "weak-strong dance" with it so that your block behaves correctly). But `controller` *itself* needs to be a normal reference. Thus (**warning**, typed directly without testing, beware of typos):

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = 
    [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[controller setInitialText:text];
// take a weak ref to pass into the block
__weak SLComposeViewController *weakController = controller;
[controller setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    // and now do the weak-strong dance with weakController...
    // and do NOT refer to controller inside the block
    SLComposeViewController *strongController = weakController;
    if (strongController != nil) {
        // ... your code here; refer only to strongController
    }
}
```

Comment: And for the canonical weak-strong dance, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#EXstrongWeakDance